# Why must the Mean Value Theorem be applied to u and v rather than to f=u+iv w.r.t. x and y individually?

Tags: complex-analysis, mean-value-theorem

In Bak and Newman's Complex Analysis book, the following proposition is stated and proven: [*Suppose fx and fy exist in a neighborhood of z. Then if fx and fy are continuous
at z and fy = i fx there, f is differentiable at z.* (statement and beginning of proof)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKfpw.png)

This proof separates $f$ into $u+iv$ and applies the Mean Value Theorem to the two difference quotients $\frac{u(z+h) - u(z)}{h}$ and $\frac{v(z+h) - v(z)}{h}$. Why can't this logic be directly applied to the difference quotient involving $f$ considered as a function of two real variables?

Comment: There isn't really any meaningful distinction between functions $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and functions $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. That being said the complex numbers turn the differentiability condition (Cauchy-Riemann equations) into a simple linear relationship between the partial derivatives. That's one of the main motivations for using them.

Comment: The usual statement of the mean value theorem is for functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.  What statement, exactly, would you like to apply to $f$?

Comment: For holomorphic functions the expression ${f(z)-f(w)\over z-w}$ is not always of the form $f'(u)$ where $u$ belongs to the segment between $w$ and $z.$ For example let $f(z)=e^z$ and $z=0$ $w=2\pi i.$ Then $f(z)=f(w),$ but $f'(u)=e^u$ does not vanish.